# Median ranks and percentile ranks

Tags: regression, correlation, normal-distribution, quantiles, ranks

In *Statistics* by Freedman et al. there's this example

> Suppose the percentile rank of one student on the SAT is $90\%$, among the first-year students. Predict his percentile rank on first-year GPA. The scatter diagram is football-shaped. In particular, the SAT scores and GPAs follow the normal curve.

Then it's calculated $z$ fron the percentile on the SAT which happens to be about $1.3$ SDs and since there is a correlation between the two of $r=0.4$ (mentioned earlier), we obtain that the GPA is $0.4 \cdot 1.3 \approx 0.5$ SDs above average, so $z \approx 0.5$: the percentile rank is $69\%$.

This is fine, but then at the end of the paragraph there's this note

> The method discussed is for **median ranks**. To see why, assume normality and $r=0.4$. Of students at the $90$th percentile on the SAT (relative to theit classmates),**about half will rank above the $\textbf{69}$th percentile on first-year GPA, and half will rank below**. The procedure for estimate average ranks is harder.

The bold parts aren't clear to me. Why this method is related to median ranks? Is the author referring to percentiles? In the second bold part it's written that half will score more and half less of $69\%$ in GPA for the people at the $90$th percentile in the SAT, but in the regression aren't we saying that $69$th percent is the **average** value for the people at that level in the SAT? Is this related to the normality assumption? Why?

Comment: You have predicted the *mean;* but the mean of a Normal distribution is its median.

Comment: @whuber ok I suspected that was the meaning, but in this reasoning it is assumed normality of GPA *given that the student is in the top 10% on the SAT*, isn't it?  in the example, instead,  it seems to be assumed unconditional normality of SAT, is it a conditional one?

Comment: The model used in that textbook is the bivariate Normal, in which the conditional distributions are always Normal.

Comment: thanks @whuber that explains everything :)